# Selecting only Text in ImageandText Datagridview column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

i'm displaying some rows in `DatagridView` which will have first column as ImageandText.when user selects any row i would like to select till the cell with text portion by keeping the image background as white.

Code used for displaying the image and text in first cell of DataGridView :

```
private void dgvLogDetails_CellPainting(object sender, 
                                            DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {                
            e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);
            PointF p = e.CellBounds.Location;
            e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
            p.X += imgList.ImageSize.Width+8;


            e.Graphics.DrawImage(imgList.Images[1], e.CellBounds.X+4, 
                                                 e.CellBounds.Y, 16, 16);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), 
                                            e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black, p);
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }
```

the above code selects the complete cell (image and text) as shown in below picture:
[image]

i wanted to have something like in below picture [Expected]:

[image]

Tried Sriram code and it is showing as below:

[image]

Comment: Am not sure, but I think `ListView` will by default have the feature you're asking. If feasible, you can use `ListView`.

Comment: actually the expected image i have shown is created using `ListView`. now i'm changing it to `DataGridView`

Comment: Oh, Disregard my comment then, See if my answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

Call `e.PaintBackground` with second parameter set to `false` which means it won't draw the selection background for you, then you can draw your own.

```
private void dgvLogDetails_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        Bitmap image = imgList.Images[1];//Get the image somewhow

        bool selected = e.State.HasFlag(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
        e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);

        PointF p = e.CellBounds.Location;
        p.X += image.Size.Width + 8;

        if (selected)
        {
            RectangleF newRect = new RectangleF(new PointF(e.CellBounds.Left + image.Size.Width, e.CellBounds.Top), new SizeF(e.CellBounds.Width - image.Size.Width, image.Height));
             using(SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor))
                 e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, newRect);
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(imgList.Images[1], e.CellBounds.X+4, 
                                             e.CellBounds.Y, 16, 16);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), 
                                        e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black, p);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Here's the output it renders:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Sriram, i have tried but still it's not unselecting the image properly, i have attached sample image in my edited post.

Comment: I think you're handling other paint events and doing some other paintings. Otherwise this should work, I just tested with a simple data it worked as expected. Cross check what is your `ImageSize` etc. If you can't figure out, post a sample project which I can look into, by that I mean I should be able to run it to see the problem (including images also). I'll try to help.

Comment: Yes :) its working fine after changing the height and width in if block, Thank you Sriram.